# Comparison Boost.Odeint vs Scipy.integrate.odeint?

Tags: python, c++, boost, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have recently stumpled upon the boost.odeint library and I  am surprised about the number of possibilities and configurability. However, having used  scipy.integrate.odeint extensively (which is essentially a wrapper to ODEPACK in fortran) I wonder how their performances compare. I know that boost.odeint also comes with parallelization, which is not possible with scipy (as far as I know) which would increase performance then a lot, but I am asking for the single core case. 
However, since I would have to wrap boost.odeint (using cython or boost.python) into python in that case, maybe someone of you has done that already? This would be a great achivement, since all the analysis possibilites are much more advanced in python.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from comparing the lists of available steppers for
Boost.odeint and scipy.integrate.ode, the only algorithm implemented by both is
the Dormand-Prince fifth order stepper, `dopri5`. You could compare the
efficiency of the two implementations of this algorithm in Python by using
[this Cython wrapper](https://github.com/bjodah/pyodeint) to Boost.odeint (it does not expose all the
steppers provided by Boost.odeint, but does expose `dopri5`).

Depending on your definition of "testing performance" you could also compare
different algorithms, but this is obviously not the same thing as comparing
two implementations of the same algorithm.